# Oracle categorizing alert log error messages

Tags: oracle

We can find oracle alert log error messages by querying in `v$diag_alert_ext` where `message_text` LIKE `'%ORA-%'`. I want to categorize the error messages like

- OS errors
- DB errors
- Listener errors

  - Local Listener Errors
  - Scan Listener Errors

Is it possible to do so by querying in the `v$diag_alert_ext` table? What is the way to do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that contains that. I do know that the database alert log is not going to contain any listener errors.  They are reported by the listener, which is a completely separate process, of which the database is totally oblivious.  I'd ask _why_ you want such information. Assuming it even exists, what would you do with it? What business decisions would be based on it?

Comment: @EdStevens We're building a monitoring application for oracle. We need to categorize the log errors mentioned in the question.
For listener errors, we can extract information from listener log files. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: The question remains - why do you "need" to categorize the errors?  So, you think you would like for your monitoring app to report, but this is still not a 'need'.  Try this though experiment. Suppose it is absolutely proven that no such categorization exists anywhere in oracle.  Now, what becomes of your "need"?  Just as an observation, I've been working with oracle since version 7.3 and have never heard of such a message categorization.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Database Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/V-DIAG_ALERT_EXT.html#GUID-7EC93FE0-FF30-4A94-92BC-785E2BCB38F3) I see that the view `V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT` contains a `MESSAGE_GROUP` column. Maybe this column contains such kind of information.

I am not aware of a view that contains such information. I searched for `*us.msg` files in the $ORACLE_HOME directories  and subdirectories of a 12.2 installation by executing `find $ORACLE_HOME -name '*us.msg'` and found the file `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/mesg/oraus.msg` that contains error messages in increasing order of error number and often containing a comment lines that describes the type of the error numbers in the following range. I extracted these comment lines. The output is shown in the following code block. There are more captions in comments that have a format thast will not ber recognized by this grep command.

```
 grep '^/ [0-9]'  $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/mesg/oraus.msg
/ 10 - 49 user session and session switching errors
/ 70 .. 90 generic debugger errors
/ 91 .. 95 ksm large_pool_size and large_pool_min_alloc size errors
/ 101 .. 149 shared server errors
/ 150 .. 159 Oracle*XA errors
/ 160 .. 199 Distributed transaction errors (continued)
/ 200 .. 249 control file management errors
/ 250 .. 299 archival & media recovery errors
/ 300..369 - Redo File errors
/ 370-389 kcb external errors
/ 390-399: more Redo log errors
/ 400-420: KCK errors
/ 436-439: Oracle licensing ercs
/ 440-460 Detached process startup errors
/ 469-525 Detached process death errors (signaled in foreground)
/ 00526-00565
/ 00570-00599 SQL*Connect Opening & Reading Files
/ 00710 - 00719 reserved for tablespace rename feature
/ 1070 - 1099: V6 program interface errors
/ 1100 to 1279: db file errors (continue at 63000)
/ 1384 - 1396 Reserved for 4K block size log file errors
/ 1490 - 1499 Analyze Parse and Execution Errors
/ 1500 - 1699 V6 Execution errors
/ 2040 .. 2099 - Reserved for distributed update
/ 2100 .. 2139 - Reserved for precompiler runtime (SQLLIB)
/ 2140 .. 2499 - V6 parser errors continued
/ 6571-6579 Reserved for Plsql functions called from Sql
/ 6581-6591 Reserved for European OEM Ports (contact: egroenen.nl)
/ 6600-6699 Reserved for more SQL*Net errors
/ 6700-6899 Reserved for TLI SQL*NET driver errors
/ 6900-6999 Reserved for more SQL*Net errors
/ 06609 is not used by the LU6.2 Driver.
/ 6700-6899 Reserved for TLI SQL*NET driver errors
/ 6900-6999 Reserved for more SQL*Net errors
/ 7000-7099 Reserved for SQL*CONNECT/DB2 errors
/ 7100-7199 Reserved for SQL*CONNECT/IMS errors
/ 7200 - 7499 Reserved for UNIX OSD errors
/ 7500-7999 VMS OSD ERRORS
/ 7700 - 7720: sksarch errors
/ 7721-7729 scg overflow errors
/ 7740 - 7760 error message file errors
/ 7820-7839  SSP error messages
/ 7840-7859 SLLF error messages
/ 7880 - 7889 Error message for sd
/ 8000 - 8174  Data layer error messages
/ 8175 - 8190 Discrete transaction error messages
/ 8200 - 8399 Reserved for NCUBE OSD errors
/ 8270 - 8273 Reserved nCUBE archival
/ 8273 - reserved nCUBE archival
/ 8320 - 8329 Reserved for scn.c
/ 8340-8359 Reserved for nCUBE redo server errors
/ 8362 - 8399 Reserved for nCUBE sosd errors (unassigned)
/ 8400 UTL_RAW and UTL_PG error and warning messages
/ 8401 - 8499 Reserved for APPC Gateway
/ 8500 - 8599 Reserved for Protocol Procedural Gateway for
/ 8600 - 8699 Reserved for ??? sql*connnect errors
/ 8700 - 8799 Reserved for ??? sql*connnect errors
/ 8800 - 8999 Reserved for Tandem sql*connnect errors
/ 9000 - 9099 Reserved for TERADATA sql*connnect errors
/ 9100 - 9199 Reserved for file-based sql*connnect errors
/ 9200 - 9499 Reserved for OS/2 and MSDOS OSD errors
/ 9500 - 9699 Reserved for MPE/XL OSD errors
/ 9700 - 9999 Reserved for UNIX OSD errors
/ 09720-09739 reserved for Philips MPX P9x00
/ 09786-09825 reserved for Loader V2.0
/ 10630-10639 Reserved for Online Segment Shrink
/ 09858-09859 Reserved For NeXT port
/ 09860-09869 Reserved For Oracle Europe
/ 10302 - 10318 Reserved for internal triggers
/ 10325 - 10335 reserved for recovery testing
/ 10530 -10540 reserved for lightweight threads
/ 10552 -10589 reserved for recoverable media/standby recovery
/ 10710 - 10729 are Reserved for BITMAP row sources
/ 10730 - 10800 general debugging events
/ 10780 - 10785  Reserved for LogMiner
/ 10786 - 10788  Reserved for ks*
/ 10789 - 10790 Reserved for LogMiner
/ 10791 - 10799  Reserved for Logical Standby
/ 10810 - 10825 Reserved for OLTP
/ 10826 - 10829 Reserved for upgrade/downgrade
/ 10830 - 10838 Reserved for sort and aggregation row sources
/ 10841 - 10849 Reserved for OCI
/ 10850 - 10869 Reserved for AQ
/ 10870 - 10879  Reserved for recovery layer
/ 10880 - 10882  Reserved for Java Virtual Machine
/ 10900 - 10924  Reserved for SPACE management
/ 10901 - used in 7.3.4 for disabling extent trimming for merge
/ 10970 - 10974 Reserved for Lob Access
/ 10975 - 10995 Reserved for Replication
/ 10996 - 10998 Reserved for ks*
/ 10999 End Pseudo-error debugging events
/ 11000 - 11999 Reserved for mvs sql*net errors
/ 12000 - 12099 Reserved for table materialized view errors
/ 12100 - 12299 Reserved for Net8 errors
/ 12150 - 12195   Reserved for OSN (Not to be used by TNS)
/ 12196 - 12285   NR errors reportable by OSN (returned by nricall())
/ 12286 - 12499   ---(Reserved)---
/ 12500 - 12699   See net12500.msg
/ 12196 - 12285 NR errors reportable to OSN.
/ 12300 - 12399 Reserved for Multiple Mounts
/ 12150 - 12285   See net12150.msg
/ 12286 - 12499   ---(Reserved)---
/ 12500 - 12530   NSG errors reportable by OSN (returned in cndo).
/ 12531 - 12629   NS (and NT errors reported as NS errors) reportable by OSN
/ 12630 - 12699   NA errors (returned by native services)
/ 12500 - 12530 Reserved for NSG errors reportable to OSN.
/ 12531 - 12629 ns errors reportable to osn:
/ 12606 - 12629 ns secondary errors
/ 12630 - 12699 Reserved for NA errors.
/ 12700 - 12999: Reserved.
/ 12700 - 12750 Reserved for NLS
/ 12751 - 12799 reserved for VOS
/ 12800 - 12893 Reserved for Parallel Query/Index Creation
/ 12857 - 12893 unused (parallel query/index creation messages)
/ 12874 - 12893 unused currently for PQ
/ 12894 - 12898 are reserved for asmcmd setsparseparent error messages.
/ 12899 - Stole this one for new "value too large" message
/ 12920 - 12939 reserved for database/tablespace force logging mode messages
/ 12930 - 12939 Reserved for 12c Nologging Standby Project.
/ 12940 - 12949 Reserved for server side DBVerify
/ 12950 - 12960 Reserved for Space Management
/ 12980 - 12999 Reserved for Drop Column
/ 13000 - 13499   (Reserved for Oracle Spatial)
/ 13000 - 13199   Spatial Data Option and Spatial Cartridge 8.0
/ 13200 - 13499   Spatial Cartridge 8.1.3
/ 13391 - 13499 for all GeoRaster errors
/ 13500 - 13999 reserved for Server Manageability Layer
/ 13500 - 13599 reserved for AWR
/ 13600 - 13699 reserved for the adv fmwk.
/ 13700 - 13749 reserved for the ADDM, ASH
/ 13800 - 13809 reserved for the SQL Tuning Base
/ 13810 - 13824 reserved for DBOP Monitor
/ 13825 - 13849 reserved for SQL profiles
/ 13850 - 13899 reserved for end-to-end tracing
/ 13900 - 13949 reserved for threshold-based alert
/ 13950 - 13969 reserved for MMON infrastructure
/ 13970-13998 reserved for common reporting framework
/ 14000 - 14999 reserved for Partitioned object project
/ 14000 - 14099 reserved for parsing new syntax introduced by the Partitioned
/ 14150-14249 reserved for parsing errors which may be generated
/ 14201-14239 reserved for errors which may be generated during
/ 14250-14349 reserved for errors which may be generated during
/ 14400 - 14499 reserved for execution errors introduced by the Partitioned
/ 14450 - 14499 reserved for execution errors introduced by the
/ 14601 - 14700 reserved for 9.0.2 partitioning project
/ 14650 - 14689 reserved for reference-partitioning project
/ 14690 - 14699 reserved for 32k varchar project
/ 14750 - 14799 reserved for interval-partitioning project
/ 14800 - 14849 Reserved for composite list/* partitioning
/ 14850 - 14869 Reserved for autolist partitioning
/ 14870 - 14889 Reserved for interval subpartitioning
/ 14900 - 14949 Reserved for KJAC error messages
/ 14950 - 14999 Reserved for KJAC PL/SQL error messages
/ 15000 - 15499 Reserved for Automatic Storage Management
/ 59000 - 59999 Reserved for Automatic Storage Management (e57000.msg)
/ 15000 - 15099 Used for ASM run-time errors
/ 15100 - 15179 Used for ASM SQL usage errors
/ 15180 - 15188 Used for ASMLIB related error messages
/ 15189 - 15199 Used for ASM tracing and testing errors
/ 15200 - 15206 ASM messages added in 10.2
/ 15210 - 15227 ASM SQL parsing messages added in 11.1
/ 15228 - 15229 Used for ASM testing errors
/ 15230 - 15250 ASM runtime error messages added in 11.1
/ 15252 - 15280 Reserved for TrailBlazer
/ 15380 - 15399 ASM File Group error messages
/ 15400 - 15439 ASM appliance error messages
/ 15430 - 15439 ASM Flex Disk Group Quota Group Messages
/ 15440 - 15499 ASM Volume Messages
/ 59000 - 59999 Reserved for Automatic Storage Management (e57000.msg)
/ 15500 - 15999 Reserved for Server Manageability Layer
/ 15500 - 15599 reserved for Workload Capture and Replay (KEC)
/ 15600 - 15649 reserved for Automated Maintenance Tasks (KET)
/ 15650 - 15699 reserved for Direct Access to Fixed Tables
/ 16000 - 16499 Reserved for ORACLE HOT STANDBY
/ 16100 - 16130 Reserved for Logical Standby
/ 16200 - 16374 Reserved for Logical Standby
/ 16375 - 16499 Reserved for Physical Standby
/ 16500 - 16699 Reserved for Data Guard Broker
/ 16700 - 16899 reserved for Data Guard Broker RSM errors
/ 16900 - 16949 Reserved for Data Guard Broker
/ 17000 - 17499 Reserved for JDBC
/ 17500 - 18000 Reserved for I/O subsystem
/ 17675-18000 Reserved for OFS
/ 18000 - 18099 Reserved for PLAN STABILITY
/ 19391 - 19399 are reserved for autonfs.
/ 19400 - 19499 are reserved for KOT.
/ 19500 - 19998 Reserved for Server Managed Recovery
/ 19830 - 19835: reserved for SQL Engine Errors:
/ 19926 - 19929: reserved for transport database errors
/ 21100 - 21299 Reserved for CORE
/ 21300 - 22799 Reserved for OI/KO/KG (object Interface and Subsystem)
/ 22800 - 22999 Reserved for object SQL:
/ 23000 - 23299 Reserved for object Management Subsystem (OMS)
/ 23300 - 24299 Reserved for errors from DBMS* pl/sql packages
/ 20000 - 20999 Reserved for callers of the
/ 21100 - 21299 Reserved for CORE
/ 21300 - 22799 Reserved for OI/KO/KG (object Interface and Subsystem)
/ 22275 to 22279 reserved for KOLL - LOBs
/ 22280 to 22299 reserved for LOBs - LBS(KOLB), DBMS_LOB(KKXL) and BFILE(KOLF)
/ 22799 IS THE MAXIMUM ERROR NUMBER for ORI/KO (object Interface and Subsystem)
/ 22800 - 22999 Reserved for object SQL:
/ 22999 IS THE MAXIMUM ERROR NUMBER for object SQL
/ 23000 - 23299 Reserved for object Management Subsystem (OMS)
/ 23300 - 24299 Reserved for errors from DBMS* pl/sql pakages
/ 24280 -24290 Reserved for DBMS_LOB (FILE) package
/ 24291 - 24299 Reserved for Sorted Hash Clusters
/ 24300 - 24999 Reserved for OCI/UPI/TTC/OPI/RPI/PSDs etc
/ 24500 - 24549 Reserved for OCI codepoint length semantics and UTF16
/ 24550 - 24574 Reserved for OCI et al Diagnosability
/ 24750 - 24800 Reserved for Transaction OCI
/ 24800 - 24849 Reserved for OCI Lob/File related Calls
/ 24850 - 24874 Reserved for Shared OCI
/ 24900 - 24939 Reserved for OCI Notification
/ 24940 - 24949 Reserved for Generic Notification
/ 24950 - 24959 Reserved for PL/SQL Notification
/ 25474 is reserved for dumping info
/ 25475 is reserved for debug mode
/ 26500 - 26649 Reserved for Replication (KN)
/ 26650 - 26999 Reserved for Log Based Replication Replication (KN)
/ 27000-27299 Reserved for Oracle8 Unix OSDs
/ 27000 - 27030 keep for SKGFQ (Also 27190-27229)
/ 27031 - 27099 keep for SKGFR (if more needed, allocate another range later)
/ 27100 - 27139 keep for SKGM
/ 27140-27189 RESERVED FOR SKGP
/ 27190 - 27229 reserved skgfq
/ 27231 - 27249 reserved for sskgof
/ 27250 - 27269 reserved for sm
/ 27270 - 27274 reserved for sz
/ 27300 - 27350 reserved for slos Error Reporting
/ 27351 - 27499 RESERVED FOR NEW DATABASE SCHEDULER
/ 27401 - 27410 Reserved for scheduler events
/ 27411 - 27420 Reserved for scheduler repeat interval errors
/ 27431 - 27500 Scheduler API errors continuation
/ 27500-27599 RESERVED FOR IPC ERRORS
/ 27600-27699 RESERVED FOR EXADATA (SAGE) and HOST/CELL ERRORS
/ 27700-27800 RESERVED FOR MGA
/ 27800-27900 RESERVED FOR EVENT NOTIFICATION (KSEVN)
/ 28000-28499 RESERVED FOR SECURITY RELATED ERRORS
/ 28060-28099 RESERVED FOR RADM (Real-time Application-controlled Data Masking)
/ 28065 is reserved for RADM internal error.
/ 28100-28149 RESERVED FOR FINE-GRAINED SECURITY
/ 28150-28199 RESERVED FOR N-TIER SECURITY
/ 28200-28230 RESERVED FOR THE APPLICATION ROLE
/ 28221-28230 RESERVED FOR PASSWORD/ACCOUNT ENHANCEMENT
/ 28230-28260 RESERVED FOR THE OBFUSCATION TOOLKIT
/ 28261-28270 RESERVED FOR APPLICATION CONTEXT
/ 28270-28290 RESERVED FOR PASSWORD AUTHENTICATED GLOBAL USER(KZAL)
/ 28290 - 28300 RESERVED FOR THE Kerberos Enterprise User Security
/ 28300 - 28329 RESERVED FOR THE ENTERPRISE USER SECURITY
/ 28330-28499 RESERVED FOR TRANSPARENT DATA ENCRYPTION
/ 28500-28749 RESERVED FOR THE HETEROGENEOUS SERVICES
/ 28575 - 28600 reserved for untrusted and distributed external procedures
/ 28700-28799 RESERVED FOR CODE-BASED ACCESS CONTROL
/ 29250-29299 RESERVED FOR MORE PL/SQL AND UTILITY PACKAGE ERRORS
/ 29300 - 29399 Reserved for errors from DBMS* pl/sql pakages.
/ 29300 - 29354 RESERVED FOR THE DBMS_SQL PACKAGE
/ 29355 - 29399 RESERVED FOR DBMS RESOURCE MANAGER PACKAGES
/ 29400 - 29469 Reserved for Oracle8 Data Cartridges
/ 29470 - 29489 RESERVED FOR THE DBMS_SQL PACKAGE
/ 29490 - 29499 RESERVED FOR THE DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE PACKAGE
/ 29500 - 29699 Reserved for DDL and other integration for
/ 29700-29799 reserved for Global Enqueue Service
/ 29780 -29789 Reserved for Gpnp Generic modules
/ 29800 - 29999 Reserved for Extensible Indexing project
/ 30000 - 30010 Reserved 8.1 miscellaneous features
/ 30051 - 30059 Reserved for row versions query feature
/ 30060 - 30069 Reserved for Transaction layer internal tracing
/ 30070 - 30099 Reserved for datetime/interval feature
/ 30100-30134 Reserved for OCIExtract Cartridge Services
/ 30300 - 30330 reserved for transaction recovery
/ 30665 - 30675 are reserved for 12g SQL enhancements projects
/ 32791 - 32799 are reserved for 12g SQL enhancements projects
/ 32800 - 32999 are reserved for Messaging Gateway (MGW)
/ 65535 -  (MAX ERROR NUMBER; NONE CAN BE LARGER)
/ 32800 - 32999 reserved for Oracle Messaging Gateway (MGW)
/ 40001 - 40020 RESERVED FOR BLAST
/ 40021 - 40040 RESERVED FOR GLM
/ 40101 - 40180 Generic Errors Across All Data Mining Algorithms
/ 40181 - 40200 RESERVED FOR DBMS_DATA_MINING_TRANSFORM
/ 40201 - 40250 RESERVED FOR DBMS_DATA_MINING
/ 40251 - 40260 RESERVED FOR SVM
/ 40261 - 40270 RESERVED FOR NMF
/ 40271 - 40280 RESERVED FOR ABN
/ 40281 - 40300 RESERVED FOR DMF
/ 40301 - 40320 RESERVED FOR DECISION TREE CLASSIFICATION AND REGRESSION
/ 40321 - 40340 RESERVED FOR CLUSTERING MODELS
/ 40341 - 40360 RESERVED FOR MODEL MAINTENANCE UPGRADE/DOWNGRADE MESSAGES
/ 40361 - 40380 RESERVED FOR SECURITY (PRIVILEGE/AUDIT) MESSAGES
/ 40381 - 40500 RESERVED FOR PMML IMPORT
/ 40401 - 40420 RESERVED FOR SVD
/ 40421 - 40440 RESERVED FOR UNSTRUCTURED TEXT
/ 40441 - 40500 RESERVED FOR JSON
/ 40501 - 40550 Reserved for Recovery
/ 40551 - 40600 Reserved for JSON
/ 40581-40619 JSON data guide related
/ 40620-40700 JSON related
/ 40651 - 40700 JSON related
/ 41095 is reserved for tuning
/ 41096 is reserved for tuning component state handling
/ 41097 is reserved for tuning migratability checks
/ 41098 is reserved for tracing
/ 41099 is reserved for debug mode
/ 48000 - 48099 are reserved for diagnosability framework errors
/ 48100 - 48179 are reserved for ADS portable layer
/ 48180 - 48199 are reserved for ADS OSD layer
/ 48200 - 48299 are reserved for AMS layer
/ 48300 - 48389 are reserved for AMI layer
/ 48390 - 48389 are reserved for ADM layer
/ 48400 - 48499 are reserved for ADV layer
/ 48500- 48599 are reserved for AME layer
/ 48600 - 48699 for AMH layer
/ 48800 - 48899 are reserved for ADV layer
/ 48900- 48999 are reserved for UTS layer
/ 51000 - 51999 are reserved for HM, IR diagnosability framework errors
/ 51000 - 51099 for HM infrastructure related
/ 51100 - 51189 for IR infrastructure related
/ 51190 - 51199 for DBMS_IR package errors
/ 51200 - 51399 for DATA corruption checks (physical, logical)
/ 51400 - 51499 for ASM checks
/ 51500 - 51699 for Check Name, Descriptions and Parameter Descriptions
/ 51700 - 51749 for Report Framework (dbgx)
/ 51257 is available to be used
/ 51700 - 51749 for Report Framework (dbgx)
/ 53000 - 53199 : Reserved for repository errors
/ 53200 - 53209 General Errors
/ 53210 - 53229 Source Checking Errors
/ 53230 - 53249 Destination Checking Errors
/ 53250 - 53269 Other Parameter Checking Errors
/ 57000 - 58999 are reserved for TimesTen IMDB errors
/ 15000 - 15499 Reserved for Automatic Storage Management [continued from]
/ 59000 - 59999 Reserved for Automatic Storage Management
/ 59000 - 59299 ASM run-time error messages
/ 59300 - 59399 ASM SQL usage error messages
/ 59400 - 59499 ASM tracing and testing error messages
/ 59500 - 59599 Flex ASM and Member Cluster error messages
/ 59600 - 59699 ASM Flex Disk Group (File Group, Quota Group) error messages
/ 59700 - 59749 ASM Extended Disk Group error messages
/ 59750 - 59799 ASM appliance (ODA, EXADATA) error messages
/ 59800 - 59819 ASMLIB related error messages
/ 59820 - 59849 ASM Volume Messages
/ 60000 - 60999 are reserved for SPACE MANAGEMENT
/ 61001 - 62000 are reserved for ADE Virtual Folder (RNFS)
/ 62001 - 62005 are reserved for parameter properties
/ 62006 - 62009 are reserved for XML and object replication
/ 62010 - 62029 are reserved for DB Unicode Migration Assistant Kernel-Side
/ 62031 - 62080 are reserved for Vector Processing (IMA)
/ 62081 - 62130 are reserved for Vector Encoding (DSBs)
/ 62500 - 62549 are reserved for PATTERN MATCHING
/ 62550 - 62554 are reserved for the SQL Row Limiting clause
/ 62555 - 62599 are reserved for Polymorphic Table Function
/ 63000 - 63999 are reserved for DATABASE FILE ERRORS (cont. from 1100-1279)
/ 64201 - 64299 are reserved for LOB errors
/ 64300 - 64349 are reserved for ARCHIVE COMPRESSION
/ 64350 - 64399 are reserved for In-Memory Columnar (IMC)
/ 64400 - 64599 are reserved for XDB errors
/ 64610 - 64619 are reserved for PL/SQL package UTL_CALL_STACK
/ 65000 - 65399 are reserved for CONSOLIDATED DATABASES ERRORS
/ 65400 - 64450 are reserved for CLUSTERING clause
/ 65455 - 65466 reserved for family errors
/ 65470- 65499 reserved for LOST WRITE PROTECTION
/ 65501- 65529 reserved for LOB layer errors
/ 65530 - 65534 reserved for INDEX layer errors
```